# Notepad++ Zero and capital O are the same

Tags: notepad++

Not sure how I have never noticed this before but in Notepad++ zero and capital O is the same. I just had to type in a serial from one computer to another and was reading it from Notepad++.

What do you have to do to set Notepad++ to differentiate between the two?

The image below has both zero and o chars. Are my eyes failing me?

[image: Zero and O in Notepad++]

Comment: It's not Notepad++, it's the font you are using.

Comment: Im using Courier New and in my Notepad++ its obviosly not equal. Have a look into Settings - Style.

Comment: Courier new, 0O: http://imgur.com/n6tHSDZ Looks different to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They differ in my installation. Change your Notepad++ configuration to use a font that makes the difference between the two more obvious. Settings -> Style Configurator

[Consolas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas) puts a slash through the zeros, making it really obvious.

Comment: It was set to Courier New bit I needed to tick 'Enable global font' for that one font to be used for everything. Oddly Courier New ha capital O and zero as the same. I'm now using Consolas per your recommendation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To be 100% sure what characters you're looking at you could check by converting ASCII to HEX (Plugins -> Converter -> 'ASCII -> HEX'). Are those plugins standard install? I can't remember, sorry.